# Show: $\forall a, b \in {\mathbb R^+},$ if $a^2\geq b^2$ then $a\geq b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I have this statement on my discrete math homework, and I'm having a little trouble figuring out the correct way to attack this problem:
$\forall \ a, b \in \Bbb{R}^+,$  if $a^2\geq b^2$ then $a\geq b$.
This homework assignment is about indirect forms of proof, i.e. disproving contradiction, or proving contrapositive. I've tried to look at proving the contrapositive, but I don't see how to do that. I've also tried looking at negation, but for that I would need to disprove a for all statement, and to do that I normally look for a proof of negation, which just gets me back to where I started.

Comment: Can you proceed from here, that if $a^2 \ge b^2$ then $a^2-b^2 \ge 0$?

Comment: If $0\leqslant a<b$, then $$a^2=a\cdot a \leqslant a\cdot b < b\cdot b=b^2.$$

Comment: So  after I take those starting points I just go for a direct proof?

Comment: $a^2=a*a\leq a*b\leq b*b=b$
Then restate the given statement and I win?

Comment: I think you meant $b*b=b^{\color{red}2}$; you can use that argument to prove the contrapositive, which is if $a<b$ then $a^2<b^ 2$ (note that the inequalities are actually strict)